# #document under iFrame is not loaded via selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, iframe, document

Im trying to traverse through the local .html file where there is an iFrame and the #document under this, is not getting loaded when it is running via automation using selenium.

Running via selenium driver:

```
<iframe id="xxxxx" name="yyyy">
.. Nothing is displaying ..
```

Opening the html file manually or by refreshing via browser refresh button:

```
<iframe id="xxxxx" name="yyyy">
#document
<html>...</html>
```

Note: In the same session using debug mode, if we page load it manually using browser refresh, the #document gets loaded but if we press "Step Over" in debug mode and move to next step, then again #document goes missing.

Tried all the below page load but the result is same: #document under iFrame goes missing as soon as any step is carried out via driver object.

PFB the page refresh which were tried,

```
public void driver_refresh() {
        getDriver().navigate().refresh();
        wait_for_element(3);
    }

    public void action_refresh() {
        Actions act = new Actions(getDriver());
        Action a1= act.keyDown(Keys.F5).keyUp(Keys.F5).build();
        a1.perform();
    }

    public void js_refresh() {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("history.go(0)");
        wait_for_element(3);
    }

    public void robot_refresh() throws Exception {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    }

    public void robot_refresh_f5() throws Exception {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F5);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F5);
        wait_for_element(5);
    }

    public void waitForLoad() {
        new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
                ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return 
        document.readyState").equals("complete"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All - Checked other steps before a point where i faced issue to see whether the #document was loaded in run time but it was not and it was still able to do those actions.

Hence, checked my full code and I was doing a page refresh in between, so the page objects were lost in runtime because I have page factory of elements.

Now removed the page refresh in between and continued in the same session - Though #document is not loaded, the required actions from selenium webdriver is performed.